# .htaccess replace .php with / for every PHP file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get the following functionality to work in PHP without a framework.  I don't want to have to worry about setting up a super complicated framework for every PHP application I do.

`http://domain.com/sign_up.php
becomes
http://domain.com/sign_up/`

`http://domain.com/user.php?id=432
becomes
http://domain.com/user/?id=432`

Or if there is a way to get that to become `http://domain.com/user/432` but i'm not sure how to handle multiple `$_GET` variables in that scenario so that's optional.

This works pretty well so far:

`RewriteRule ^sign_up/([^/]*)$ /sign_up.php?p=$1 [L]`

The only problem is I have to do that for every single php file i'm using which can become a lot.

What is a universal way to do it for all php files?

## UPDATES:

This one line is working perfectly:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]`

Only issue is it doesn't auto redirect PHP

For example, I want to 301 auto redirect:

`http://domain.com/file.php
to
http://domain.com/file/`

And

`http://domain.com/file.php?var1=value&var2=value
to
http://domain.com/file/?var1=value&var2=value`

If anyone can think of a better way to handle query string values in a more SEO friendly way that would be awesome! But otherwise this is working pretty great so far.

## MORE UPDATES:

Now this is working:
`http://domain.com/file/` - to -
`http://domain.com/file.php`

Both of those point to the same page with this htaccess code:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]`

However `http://domain.com/file` without the trailing `/` returns a page not found error.

Also I need to know how to auto redirect `http://domain.com/file.php` to `http://domain.com/file/`

## MOSTLY WORKING HTACCESS

This .htaccess works beautifully:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]
```

The only thing it doesn't do is auto redirect if they go directly to `http://domain.com/file.php` it does not redirect to `http://domain.com/file/` but everything else about it is working.

Comment: This is a regexp, right? Use `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/([^/*)$ /$1?p=$2 [L]` or something like that

Comment: Created Internal Server Error

Comment: Still creating internal server error

Comment: Did you get it working? Any updates on the issue?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal See the `Mostly Working HTACCESS` note above, it's super close to working exactly how I want

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f # but php exists
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ $1.php?p=$2 [L]
```

---

> However http://domain.com/file without the trailing / returns a page not found error.

That's because your rule does not match unless there's a `/` at the end.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]
                  ^
```

You can make it optional with `?` as

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Note, that `/` does not need a `\` before it. It works with or without it.

> Also I need to know how to auto redirect http://domain.com/file.php to http://domain.com/file/

```
# Rewrite original .php request to new URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R,L]

# Resolve the new URLs to .php files
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

If you get this working first, we can see what we can do about the query parameters later.

---

Your final htaccess could look like

```
# Rewrite original .php request to new URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R,L]

# Force a trailing / if not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..{3,4}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]

# Redirect to php if not an existing dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This is really close:
`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ $1.php?p=$2 [L]`
On it's own works but it messes up all the images on the site which is what I'm guessing the other lines are accounting for, but if I include them I get an internal server error.

Comment: Actually the !-d/f conditions make sure we exclude any existing dirs/files which should work for images etc. also. Where are the resource files stored? Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: No, no other rules are in the .htaccess file

Comment: Adding this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC]` Get's it to work without the `/` however it breaks it if there is a `/` at the end.  I'm wondering if there is a way to force it to always have the trailing `/`

Comment: @RaviThapliyal See the notes in the edit above.  It's really really close.

Comment: @Jordash You can fix the rule to work with `/` by using `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]` but since you're forcing the trailing slash now, your final htaccess could look like as shown in my update.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redirect with trailing parameter
RewriteRule ^([\w]+).php?p=([\w]+)$ $1/$2/  [QSA,R=301]

# redirect bare php files
RewriteRule ^([\w]+).php$ $1/  [QSA,R=301]

# make sure it's not a request to an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# make sure we have a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/  [QSA,R=301]

# internally point to the right file
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The `[R=301]` appendixes redirect the browser to the new URL with a 301, moved permanently status header. That way the browser will know where to find the right url in the future, without asking the server.

Also, sometimes an .htaccess checker is useful: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ Do note, the tool doesn't work with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`.

Comment: But when I go directly to a PHP file it doesn't re-direct, checking out that tool, seems really useful.

Comment: Also I just realized this breaks whenever there are GET variables being passed (ex. `http://domain.com/file/?var1=value` )

Comment: Wouldn't you pass GET variables in this format instead "http://domain.com/file?var1=value"   that extra / seems very akward

Comment: Either way, it doesn't really matter, the ONLY way that works currently is with the trailing /

Comment: See my update. You can add QSA to the appendixes. This will pass the rest of the query string along.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `domain.com/help` to load `domain.com/help.php` and still load all the jpg/png/css/img etc, use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```